# How to cache nginx with acc and expired time on url

Tags: nginx, ubuntu

(1) Source link:

> https://bato.to/chapter/2170006

(2) Image url example:

> https://xfs-s107.batcg.org/comic/7006/255/63d8e0e22aa1d12922877552/24710008_2160_3070_989124.webp

(3) Query:

> ?acc=s5WX_Vh52fc9nAuSzakSyg&exp=1689757290

Every time I reload (1) page, it will random add (3) with ?acc=CONTENT&exp=NUMBER to (2), it will become:

(4) Full image url with query

> https://xfs-s107.batcg.org/comic/7006/255/63d8e0e22aa1d12922877552/24710008_2160_3070_989124.webp?acc=s5WX_Vh52fc9nAuSzakSyg&exp=1689757290

- When I run (2) will be **403 Forbidden**
  [Result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YfBP.png)
- When I run (4) it will show **Real image**
  [Result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoJ2d.png)
- But after time, (4) can't access anymore, I think because it expired.

So anyone know how config like (4) for nginx, I tried to find keys like "nginx cache with query", "nginx image cache query" on google but can't find the way.

Comment: Can you share the configuration of your nginx you have set up for this? Without context it is difficult to understand what is the goal.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Please don't link pictures of text you can copy and paste here. Including the relevant log entries is always a good idea.

Comment: what is the business related question in here? please read carefully [ask]